# Primes factors of numbers of the form $a^2-ab+b^2$

Tags: number-theory

I was reading an article<sup>*</sup> and came across the claim that any prime equal to 2 or of the form $6m-1$ occur an even number of times in all numbers of the form $a^2-ab+b^2$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, and that this is a "simple result from Gauss' theory of quadratic residues." I'm not quite sure what they're referring to by this "theory of quadratic residues", as it doesn't seem obvious to me how it could be proved by quadratic reciprocity or Gauss' lemma.

What 'theory of quadratic residues' are they talking about and how does it prove this claim?

---

<sup>*</sup>The article can be found [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3618130):

- Mackinnon, Nick. “Sophie Germain: Or Was Gauss a Feminist?” The Mathematical Gazette, vol. 74, no. 470, Mathematical Association, 1990, pp. 346–51, https://doi.org/10.2307/3618130.

The specific part mentioned above occurs on pages 349–50:

> > Theorem: If $a^3 + b^3$ if of the form $s^2 + 3 t^2$, then so is $a + b$.
>
> The proof depends on a result of Euler and a simple result from Gauss’ theory of quadratic residues. Euler’s result says that a number $N$ can be written in the form $s^2 + 3 t^2$ if and only if in the prime factorisation of $N$ each prime $p$ equal to $2$ or of the form $6a - 1$ must occur an even number of times. Gauss’ result says that any such prime occurs an even number of times in the factorisation of numbers of the form $a^2 - ab + b^2$. The theorem now follows easily from looking at the prime factorisation of
> $$
> a^3 + b^3 = (a + b) (a^2 - ab + b^2).
> $$

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer

Comment: Consider the example $5^2 -5*11 + 11^2=91=7*13$. Both $5,11$ are of the form $6m-1$, yet the solution is made of strictly of primes of the form $6m+1$.

Comment: Hint : $$a^2-ab+b^2=\frac{(2a-b)^2+3b^2}{4}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with quadratic reciprocity, just elementary properties of the group of nonzero residues. Suppose $p \mid a^2 - ab + b^2$. Then $a^3 + b^3 = (a + b) (a^2 - ab + b^2) \equiv 0 \pmod p$. If $a, b \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$ then $(a/b)^3 \equiv -1 \pmod p$, so either the unit group has an element of order 6, so $6 \mid p-1$, or $a/b \equiv -1 \pmod p$. In the latter case we have $0 \equiv  a^2 - ab + b^2 \equiv 3a^2 \pmod p$, so $p = 3$. Otherwise, $a$ and $b$ are divisible by $p$, say $a = pa_0$ and $b = pb_0$, so $a^2 - ab + b^2 = p^2(a_0^2 - a_0 b_0 + b_0^2)$. Iterating the argument shows that $p$ divides $a^2 - ab + b^2$ an even number of times.

Comment: This can also be proven with quadratic reciprocity , although this might not be the easiest or most elegant approach.